# Numpy resize and fill with specific value

Tags: python, numpy, resize

How can i resize a numpy array and fill it with a specific value (if some dimension is extended) ?

I find a way to extend my array with **np.pad** but I can't shorten it:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.ndarray((5, 5), dtype=np.uint16)
>>> a
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint16)
>>> np.pad(a, ((0, 1), (0,3)), mode='constant', constant_values=9)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 9, 9],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 9, 9],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 9, 9],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 9, 9],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 9, 9],
       [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]], dtype=uint16)
```

And if i use **resize** i can't specify the value that I want to use.

```
>>> a.fill(5)
>>> a.resize((2, 7))
>>> a
array([[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]], dtype=uint16)
```

But i would like

```
>>> a
array([[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9]], dtype=uint16)
```

After some test I create this function but it's only work when you change x_value or with a lower y_value, if you need to increase y dimension it doesn't work, why ?

```py
VALUE_TO_FILL = 9
def resize(self, x_value, y_value):
    x_diff = self.np_array.shape[0] - x_value
    y_diff = self.np_array.shape[1] - y_value
    self.np_array.resize((x_value, y_value), refcheck=False)
    if x_diff < 0:
        self.np_array[x_diff:, :] = VALUE_TO_FILL
    if y_diff < 0:
        self.np_array[:, y_diff:] = VALUE_TO_FILL
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Resize an existing array and fill with zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251635/python-resize-an-existing-array-and-fill-with-zeros)

Comment: I have already try the solutions in this subject but i can't make it work for my problem (as i said i try np.pad but i can't shorten my array with this function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your array has a fixed size data buffer.  You can reshape the array without changing that buffer.  You can take a slice (`view`) without changing the buffer.  But you can't add values to the array without changing the buffer.

In general `resize` returns an new array with a new data buffer.

`pad` is a complex function to handle general cases.  But the simplest approach is to create the `empty` target array, fill it, and then copy the input into the right place.

Alternatively `pad` could create the fill arrays and concatenate them with the original.  But `concatenate` also makes the empty return and copies.

A do it yourself pad with clipping could be structured as:

```
n,m = X.shape
R = np.empty((k,l))
R.fill(value)
<calc slices from n,m,k,l>
R[slice1] = X[slice2]
```

Calculating the slices may require `if-else` tests or equivalent `min/max`.  You can probably work out those details.

---

This may be all that is needed

```
R[:X.shape[0],:X.shape[1]]=X[:R.shape[0],:R.shape[1]]
```

That's because there's no problem if a slice is larger than the dimension.

```
In [37]: np.arange(5)[:10]
Out[37]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Thus, for example:

```
In [38]: X=np.ones((3,4),int)    
In [39]: R=np.empty((2,5),int)
In [40]: R.fill(9)

In [41]: R[:X.shape[0],:X.shape[1]]=X[:R.shape[0],:R.shape[1]]

In [42]: R
Out[42]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 9],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

To shorten it, you can use negative values in slice :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.ndarray((5, 5), dtype=np.uint16)
>>> a
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint16)
>>> b = a[0:-1,0:-3]
>>> b
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0]], dtype=uint16)
```

Comment: Yes but i want to resize my array so sometimes i need to decrease one dimension and increase the other, i would like to know the best way to do it (and use the less if statement)