# Fastest way to expand the values of a numpy matrix in diagonal blocks

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, diagonal

I'm searching for a fast way for resize the matrix in a special way, without using for-loops:
I have a squared Matrix:

```
matrix = [[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
          [ 6, 7, 8, 9,10],
          [11,12,13,14,15],
          [16,17,18,19,20],
          [21,22,23,24,25]]
```

and my purpose is to resize it 3 (or n) times, where the values are diagonal blocks in the matrix and other values are zeros:

```
goal_matrix = [[ 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0],
               [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5, 0],
               [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5],
               [ 6, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0,10, 0, 0],
               [ 0, 6, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0,10, 0],
               [ 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0,10],
               [11, 0, 0,12, 0, 0,13, 0, 0,14, 0, 0,15, 0, 0],
               [ 0,11, 0, 0,12, 0, 0,13, 0, 0,14, 0, 0,15, 0],
               [ 0, 0,11, 0, 0,12, 0, 0,13, 0, 0,14, 0, 0,15],
               [16, 0, 0,17, 0, 0,18, 0, 0,19, 0, 0,20, 0, 0],
               [ 0,16, 0, 0,17, 0, 0,18, 0, 0,19, 0, 0,20, 0],
               [ 0, 0,16, 0, 0,17, 0, 0,18, 0, 0,19, 0, 0,20],
               [21, 0, 0,22, 0, 0,23, 0, 0,24, 0, 0,25, 0, 0],
               [ 0,21, 0, 0,22, 0, 0,23, 0, 0,24, 0, 0,25, 0],
               [ 0, 0,21, 0, 0,22, 0, 0,23, 0, 0,24, 0, 0,25]]
```

It should do something like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251635/python-resize-an-existing-array-and-fill-with-zeros), but without unnecessary zero padding.
**Is there any mapping, padding or resizing function for doing this in a fast way?**

Comment: note that your matrix is *not* symmetric

Comment: @TCMolenaar I think he means "square matrix"

Comment: `np.kron(matrix, np.eye(3, dtype=int))`

Comment: `np.einsum('ij,kl->ikjl', matrix, np.eye(3, dtype=int)).reshape(len(matrix) * 3,-1)` is ~4x faster than `np.kron` for the example array.

Comment: Is there a good reason to reject the for loop? I tested several solutions, among which the simple use of for loops and slice assignments is much faster than other solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO, it is inappropriate to reject the for loop blindly. Here I provide a solution without the for loop. When n is small, its performance is better than that of @MichaelSzczesny and @SalvatoreDanieleBianco solutions:

```
def mechanic(mat, n):
    ar = np.zeros((*mat.shape, n * n), mat.dtype)
    ar[..., ::n + 1] = mat[..., None]
    return ar.reshape(
        *mat.shape,
        n,
        n
    ).transpose(0, 3, 1, 2).reshape([s * n for s in mat.shape])
```

This solution obtains the expected output through a slice assignment, then transpose and reshape, but copies will occur in the last step of reshaping, making it inefficient when n is large.

After a simple test, I found that the solution that simply uses the for loop has the best performance:

```
def mechanic_for_loop(mat, n):
    ar = np.zeros([s * n for s in mat.shape], mat.dtype)
    for i in range(n):
        ar[i::n, i::n] = mat
    return ar
```

---

Next is a benchmark test using [`perfplot`](https://pypi.org/project/perfplot/). The test functions are as follows:

```
import numpy as np


def mechanic(mat, n):
    ar = np.zeros((*mat.shape, n * n), mat.dtype)
    ar[..., ::n + 1] = mat[..., None]
    return ar.reshape(
        *mat.shape,
        n,
        n
    ).transpose(0, 3, 1, 2).reshape([s * n for s in mat.shape])


def mechanic_for_loop(mat, n):
    ar = np.zeros([s * n for s in mat.shape], mat.dtype)
    for i in range(n):
        ar[i::n, i::n] = mat
    return ar


def michael_szczesny(mat, n):
    return np.einsum(
        'ij,kl->ikjl',
        mat,
        np.eye(n, dtype=mat.dtype)
    ).reshape([s * n for s in mat.shape])


def salvatore_daniele_bianco(mat, n):
    repeated_matrix = mat.repeat(n, axis=0).repeat(n, axis=1)
    col_ids, row_ids = np.meshgrid(
        np.arange(repeated_matrix.shape[0]),
        np.arange(repeated_matrix.shape[1])
    )
    repeated_matrix[(col_ids % n) - (row_ids % n) != 0] = 0
    return repeated_matrix


functions = [
    mechanic,
    mechanic_for_loop,
    michael_szczesny,
    salvatore_daniele_bianco
]
```

Resize times unchanged, array size changes:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from itertools import accumulate, repeat
    from operator import mul
    from perfplot import bench

    bench(
        functions,
        list(accumulate(repeat(2, 11), mul)),
        lambda n: (np.arange(n * n).reshape(n, n), 5),
        xlabel='ar.shape[0]'
    ).show()
```

Output:
[image: enter link description here]

Resize times changes, array size unchanged:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from itertools import accumulate, repeat
    from operator import mul
    from perfplot import bench

    ar = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
    bench(
        functions,
        list(accumulate(repeat(2, 11), mul)),
        lambda n: (ar, n),
        xlabel='resize times'
    ).show()
```

Output:
[image: enter link description here]

---

---

Comment: Very nice! `np.kron` would have been interesting because it is notoriously slow. Of course there is also the boring broadcast solution `(matrix[...,None,None] * np.eye(3, dtype=int)[None,None]).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(15,-1)` (slightly faster than `einsum`, but I haven't benchmarked larger arrays).

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny The broadcasting solution is a little slow when the resize times are large (more than 10^2), but I don't want to update the pictures (the image upload system of SO is currently malfunctioning).

Answer (score 4):

Input:

```
matrix = np.array([[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
          [ 6, 7, 8, 9,10],
          [11,12,13,14,15],
          [16,17,18,19,20],
          [21,22,23,24,25]])
```

Solution:

```
repeated_matrix = matrix.repeat(3, axis=0).repeat(3, axis=1)
col_ids, row_ids = np.meshgrid(np.arange(repeated_matrix.shape[0]), np.arange(repeated_matrix.shape[1]))
repeated_matrix[(col_ids%3)-(row_ids%3)!=0]=0
```

Output (`repeated_matrix`):

```
array([[ 1,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  3,  0,  0,  4,  0,  0,  5,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  3,  0,  0,  4,  0,  0,  5,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  3,  0,  0,  4,  0,  0,  5],
       [ 6,  0,  0,  7,  0,  0,  8,  0,  0,  9,  0,  0, 10,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  6,  0,  0,  7,  0,  0,  8,  0,  0,  9,  0,  0, 10,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  6,  0,  0,  7,  0,  0,  8,  0,  0,  9,  0,  0, 10],
       [11,  0,  0, 12,  0,  0, 13,  0,  0, 14,  0,  0, 15,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 11,  0,  0, 12,  0,  0, 13,  0,  0, 14,  0,  0, 15,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 11,  0,  0, 12,  0,  0, 13,  0,  0, 14,  0,  0, 15],
       [16,  0,  0, 17,  0,  0, 18,  0,  0, 19,  0,  0, 20,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 16,  0,  0, 17,  0,  0, 18,  0,  0, 19,  0,  0, 20,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 16,  0,  0, 17,  0,  0, 18,  0,  0, 19,  0,  0, 20],
       [21,  0,  0, 22,  0,  0, 23,  0,  0, 24,  0,  0, 25,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 21,  0,  0, 22,  0,  0, 23,  0,  0, 24,  0,  0, 25,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 21,  0,  0, 22,  0,  0, 23,  0,  0, 24,  0,  0, 25]])
```

basically you can define your custom function to do this on any matrix like:

```
def what_you_whant(your_matrix, n_repeats):
  repeated_matrix = your_matrix.repeat(n_repeats, axis=0).repeat(n_repeats, axis=1)
  col_ids, row_ids = np.meshgrid(np.arange(repeated_matrix.shape[1]), np.arange(repeated_matrix.shape[0]))
  repeated_matrix[(col_ids%n_repeats)-(row_ids%n_repeats)!=0]=0
  return repeated_matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Michael Szczesny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14277722/michael-szczesny) suggested in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74054138/fastest-way-to-expand-the-values-of-a-numpy-matrix-in-diagonal-blocks#comment130754971_74054138):
The fastest way is to use the einsum, and multiplicate the matrix with the identification matrix with size of the block and reshape it to the expanded size:

```
np.einsum('ij,kl->ikjl', matrix, np.eye(3)).reshape(len(matrix) * 3, -1)
```

another more straight forward answer (but ~4x slower) is to use the Kronecker product. Again multiplying the matrix with the identity matrix:

```
np.kron(matrix, np.eye(3))
```